# Extract same key from array and count same values in new array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 15
            [orario] => 10:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => 15
            [orario] => 11:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => 15
            [orario] => 09:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [status] => 12
            [orario] => 09:00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [status] => 12
            [orario] => 09:00
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [status] => 12
            [orario] => 10:00
        )

)
```

So I want a new array where I have the count of similar status, in this case, status=12, I have 2 values with status 12 and orario = 09:00, 1 case with status=12 and orario = 10:00

```
Array
(
    09:00 => 2
    10:00 => 1
)
```

with array_column I have no filter

```
$stat_orario = array_column($the_array, 'status', 'orario');
print_r($stat_orario);
```

So I have the total result

```
Array
(
    09:00 => 3
    10:00 => 2
    11:00 => 1
)
```

Comment: [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) + [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array_count_values)

Comment: Please add some of the code that you have written to try and answer your own question.

Comment: Hi, thanks but how can I filter only some [status]. If I use array_column I have no filter.

Comment: @geeves I have a loop to populate the array for others functions. So I don't want change the loop because I need some values after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try following code :

```
$arr = array(
        array('status'=>15,'orario'=>'10:00'),
        array('status'=>15,'orario'=>'11:00'),
        array('status'=>15,'orario'=>'09:00'),
        array('status'=>12,'orario'=>'09:00'),
        array('status'=>12,'orario'=>'09:00'),
        array('status'=>12,'orario'=>'10:00')
    );

    $orario = array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'orario'));
```

Output is :

```
Array
(
    [10:00] => 2
    [11:00] => 1
    [09:00] => 3
)
```

Comment: Hi, but I want to filter with only status = 12

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I find thanks to Forge Web Design

```
$arr = array(
        array('status'=>15,'orario'=>'10:00'),
        array('status'=>15,'orario'=>'11:00'),
        array('status'=>15,'orario'=>'09:00'),
        array('status'=>12,'orario'=>'09:00'),
        array('status'=>12,'orario'=>'09:00'),
        array('status'=>12,'orario'=>'10:00')
    );

// I transform the array with only status = 12, but I have to do this for every status I want to extract values

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if ($arr[$key]['status'] == '12')
        $status_12[$key] = $val;
}
    $orario = array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'orario'));
```

Output now is only status = 12

```
Array
(
    [10:00] => 1
    [09:00] => 2
)
```